# Is there a general way to differentiate between homeomorphism and homotopy equivalence in a mental picture?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, soft-question, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ are two topological spaces.

1. The spaces $X$ and $Y$ are said to be homeomorphic if there exists a homeomorphism between them.
2. The spaces $X$ and $Y$ are said to be homotopy equivalent if there exist continuous maps $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow X$ such that $g \circ f$ is homotopic to $1_X$ and $f \circ g$ is homotopic to $1_Y$.

In the beginning of a Topology course we sometimes hear that Topology is like a *rubber sheet geometry*. **Also sometimes we have proved several results using these kinds of intuitions to begin with** like $\sum S^n = S^{n+1} $ ,$CS^n= D^{n+1}$. Here one can explicitly find  homeomorphisms between ($S^{n+1}$ and $\sum S^n$) and ($D^{n+1}$ and $CS^n$). (Here $\sum$ is suspension and $C$ is the cone.)

Little strangely, one will use the *"same kind of intuition"* to show that any convex set like $X = R^n$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y=$ **"a point"** by linear homotopy. But here obviously  $R^n$ is not homeomorphic to a point (as clearly bijectivity fails).

But the real problem starts **with the intuition** when $Y$ is not as simple as *"a point"* .

**My question:**

Is there a general way to differentiate between homeomorphism and homotopy equivalent *intuitively in a mental picture*? Or in other words, whenever we draw a mental picture of an object made of rubber like material, then when we squeeze it or extend it, what do we actually subconsciously think ? Is it homotopy, homeomorphism, deformation retract,...etc.?

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 4):

My intuition is that bending, squeezing and extending is all homeomorphism. These are easily reversible, they don't loose (topological) information.

More aggressive deformations, e.g. collapsing a dimension (I'm thinking about collapsing $[0,1]^2$ to $[0,1]\times\{0\}$), would be a deformation retraction. Some information (e.g. the dimension) may be lost in the process. Of course homeomorphism is a special case of such deformation.

Note that deformation retractions and homotopy equivalences are very closely related: two spaces are homotopy equivalent if and only if they are both deformation retracts of some superspace. And so I usually think about them as pretty much the same thing, even though technically they are not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.